# Change brightness on a greyscale image with transparent background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I use a function to change brightness of a picture (without use openGL), which works well.

I use another function to convert my image in grayscale, which works well too.

But when i combine them, when i apply my brightness function on the grayscale image, i got some stripes on the image, and when the background is transparent (alpha 0) it is replaced by a black background. Do you any have any idea?

Please find below my grayscale function and the brightness function as well :

```
// ## Brightness without OpenGL call
+(UIImage *) changeImageBrightness:(UIImage *)aInputImage withFactor:(float)aFactor
{
    CGImageRef img=aInputImage.CGImage;
    CFDataRef dataref = CGDataProviderCopyData(
                  CGImageGetDataProvider(aInputImage.CGImage));

    int length=CFDataGetLength(dataref);
    UInt8 *data=(UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr(dataref);

    // Perform operation on pixels
    for(int index=0;index<length;index+=4) {
        // Go For BRIGHTNESS
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
            if(data[index+i]+aFactor<0) {
                data[index+i]=0;
            } else {
                if(data[index+i]+aFactor>255) {
                    data[index+i]=255;
                } else {
                    data[index+i]+=aFactor;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // .. Take image attributes
    size_t width=CGImageGetWidth(img);
    size_t height=CGImageGetHeight(img);
    size_t bitsPerComponent=CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(img);
    size_t bitsPerPixel=CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(img);
    size_t bytesPerRow=CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img);

    // .. Do the pixel manupulation
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace=CGImageGetColorSpace(img);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo=CGImageGetBitmapInfo(img);
    CFDataRef newData=CFDataCreate(NULL,data,length);
    CGDataProviderRef provider=CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(newData);

    // .. Get the Image out of this raw data
    CGImageRef newImg = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent,
                bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorspace, bitmapInfo, provider,
                                      NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // .. Prepare the image from raw data
    UIImage* rawImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImg];

    // .. done with all,so release the references
    CFRelease(newData);
    CGImageRelease(newImg);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CFRelease(dataref);
   // return rawImage.CGImage;
    UIImage *imageApresFiltreEtRotationCGI = [UIImage
                        imageWithCGImage:rawImage.CGImage];
    return imageApresFiltreEtRotationCGI;
}

+ (UIImage *)convertImageToGrayScale:(UIImage *)image
{
    // Create image rectangle with current image width/height
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    // Grayscale color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    // Create bitmap content with current image size and grayscale colorspace
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, image.size.width,
                 image.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);
    // Draw image into current context, with specified rectangle
    // using previously defined context (with grayscale colorspace)
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, [image CGImage]);
    /* changes start here */
    // Create bitmap image info from pixel data in current context
    CGImageRef grayImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // release the colorspace and graphics context
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    // make a new alpha-only graphics context
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, image.size.width,
                 image.size.height, 8, 0, nil, kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    // draw image into context with no colorspace
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, [image CGImage]);
    // create alpha bitmap mask from current context
    CGImageRef mask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // release graphics context
    CGContextRelease(context);
    // make UIImage from grayscale image with alpha mask
    UIImage *grayScaleImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:
             CGImageCreateWithMask(grayImage, mask) scale:image.scale
                                       orientation:image.imageOrientation];
    // release the CG images
    CGImageRelease(grayImage);
    CGImageRelease(mask);
    // return the new grayscale image
    return grayScaleImage;
    /* changes end here */
}
```

Here is the picture i got.

[image: http://ch4v.atopiq.net/background-php/IMG_0143.JPG]

The background behind the baby was transparent before i made the grey/scale and light transformation.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you're seeing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the FAQ so you can get higher quality answers to your questions.

Please provide some information as to exactly what you want, what you have tried so far, and what isn't working.

Comment: Good remark, i added the link to the picture

Comment: As every 4th pixel stays black, I can not help thinking there is a slight mistake in your for loops, study the indices used in there hard, I am pretty sure there lies your answer.